How to smartly encode academic semesters in RDF / Wikibase?
I have an instance of Wikibase, and I am working on a project in which I study university professors and the courses they taught (19th-20th centuries).
I would like to be able to encode information such as:

prof_1 taught course_A from semester 1 of academic year 1890-1891 to
semester 2 of academic year 1893-1894

My objective is to encode the data as directly and easily as possible so that I can build SPARQL queries to ask questions like

who did teach course_A from semester 1 1891-1892 to semester 1 1892-1893 ?

I guess the natural way to encode that would be to use qualifiers, such as Wikidata's
start time (P580) and end time (P582).
But here the "natural" chronological granularity is the academic semester, which is a priori not a "Point in time" value.
What is the best solution to encode this?

creating an entity for each academic semester, and encoding start and end dates for each of them (which will be approximate, as we do not know them exactly), so that I can simply rely on the dates themselves, using properties like "start semester" and "end semester" (I guess this is the easy way, but I feel I'm getting around a problem that could be solved thanks to RDF's flexibility);
finding a way to make academic semesters "Point in time" values, so that I can directly search in the "ordered" semesters (I don't even know if that makes sense);
any other solution I have not thought of?


There exist also academic trimesters.

Indeed! The problem would be similar, it seems to me
